How to configure debugpy for editable install?
I am trying to develop a package that I have installed with pip install -e . .
The project structure is the following:
mypackage
├── build
│   └── mypackage-0.8.83.dist-info
│       └── licenses
├── dist
├── docs
├── manual_tests
│   └── manual_test.py
├── src
│   └── mypackage
└── tests

I want to use the manual_test.py script for debugging mypackage. Among others, in such a file I have import mypackage as mypkg but when I run the debugger I get a module not found error on that line. Other packages are correctly recognized.
The debugpy configuration follows:
{
"request": "launch",
"type": "python",
"cwd": "${fileDirname}",
"program": "${file}",
"stopOnEntry": true,
"console": "integratedTerminal",
"env": {
    "PYDEVD_RESOLVE_SYMLINKS": "1",
  },
}

I read somewhere to set PYDEVD_RESOLVE_SYMLINKS=1 but it didn't help.
